# LWJGL Why does my geometry sometimes render incorrectly?

Tags: java, debugging, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

I've made a simple opengl application in java, using LWJGL and GLFW.
I created a class for rendering a textured box. It creates the vertex positions, texture coordinates, and uses a VBO. The box is rendered using `GL_TRIANGLES`.
When I start the program to test it, sometimes:
- The output is correct, I see the box rendered correctly.
- There's very big, weird (white/gray) triangle sticking out of the box.
- The box is totally deformed, like there are a lot of triangles totally random.

When I don't change any code, the result is still different every time. But sometimes the box *is* rendered correctly.

I'm quite sure my vertices *and* texture coordinates are correct.
It's hard to find what's wrong. I recreated the box class so it renders it using `GL_QUADS` (and of course rethought the vertex/texture coordinates).
But then I still get the same weird behaviour.

The hard thing is that the result is different every time the program runs, while the code isn't edited.

Here some pictures, one of a run where it's all correct:
[image: Correct rendered box]

And now I run the program again, and I get this:
[image]

And so on...

Does someone know what could be happening?
This is how I render the box:

```
texture.bind();

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texId);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

Texture.unbind();
```

It already could help if someone knows what causes the changing result.

The code of my box class:

```
package shapes;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_FLOAT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_TRIANGLES;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDisable;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDisableClientState;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDrawArrays;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnable;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnableClientState;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glTexCoordPointer;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertexPointer;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glBindBuffer;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glBufferData;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glGenBuffers;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import main.Geometry;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;

import textures.Texture;

public class TriangleBox extends Geometry {

    private float sizeX;
    private float sizeY;
    private float sizeZ;

    private short[] indices;
    private float[] texCoords;

    private int vboId;
    private int texId;
    private int indId;

    private Texture texture;

    /**
     * Creates a beam figure (a bar)
     * 
     * @param widthX
     * @param heightY
     * @param depthZ
     */
    public TriangleBox(float widthX, float heightY, float depthZ, Texture tex) {

        this.sizeX = widthX;
        this.sizeY = heightY;
        this.sizeZ = depthZ;

        this.setTexture(tex);
        this.createVertices();
        this.createVBO();
    }

    public void setTexture(Texture tex) {

        this.texture = tex;
    }

    protected void createVertices() {

        vertices = new float[] { 
                //Bottom
                0, 0, 0,    
                1, 0, 0,    
                0, 0, 1,    

                0, 0, 1,    
                1, 0, 0,    
                1, 0, 1,    

                //Top
                0, 1, 0,    
                1, 1, 0,    
                0, 1, 1,    

                0, 1, 1,    
                1, 1, 0,    
                1, 1, 1,    

                //Front
                0, 1, 1,    
                1, 1, 1,    
                0, 0, 1,    

                0, 0, 1,    
                1, 1, 1,    
                1, 0, 1,    

                //Back
                1, 1, 0,    
                0, 1, 0,    
                1, 0, 0,    

                1, 0, 0,    
                0, 1, 0,    
                0, 0, 0,    

                //Left
                0, 1, 0,    
                0, 1, 1,    
                0, 0, 0,    

                0, 0, 0,    
                0, 1, 1,
                0, 0, 1,

                //Right
                1, 1, 1,
                1, 1, 0,
                1, 0, 1,

                1, 0, 1,
                1, 1, 0,
                1, 0, 0,
        };

        texCoords = new float[] { 
                // Bottom
                0f,     .33f,
                .25f,   .33f,
                0f,     .66f,

                0f,     .66f,
                .25f,   .33f,
                .25f,   .66f,

                // Top
                .75f,   .33f,
                .50f,   .33f,
                .75f,   .66f,

                .75f,   .66f,
                .50f,   .33f,
                .50f,   .66f,

                // Front  
                0f,     1f  ,
                .25f,   1f  ,
                0f,     .66f,

                0f,     .66f,
                .25f,   1f  ,
                .25f,   .66f,

                // Back
                .25f,   0f  ,
                0f,     0f  ,
                .25f,   .33f,

                .25f,   .33f,
                0f,     0f  ,
                0f,     .33f,

                // Left
                .75f,   .33f,
                .75f,   .66f,
                1f,     .33f,

                1f,     .33f,
                .75f,   .66f,
                1f,     .66f,

                // Right
                .50f,   .66f,
                .50f,   .33f,
                .25f,   .66f,

                .25f,   .66f,
                .50f,   .33f,
                .25f,   .33f
        };
    }

    public void createVBO() {

        FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.flip();

        FloatBuffer texCoordBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(texCoords.length);
        texCoordBuffer.put(texCoords);
        texCoordBuffer.flip();

        vboId = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        texId = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    public void render() {

        texture.bind();

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texId);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length);

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        Texture.unbind();
    }
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 120

attribute vec3 position;

void main() {

    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader

```
#version 120

void main() {

    gl_FragColor = gl_Color; //vec4(0.1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: You have texture.bind() and Texture.unbind(), which means you're calling those methods on two different things. Is it supposed to be that way?

Comment: @BillHorvathII Yes, it's suposed to be that way.

Comment: Sound like something is not initialized. As Rabbid76 asked, could you show the code where you set view and projection?

Comment: Now I added the code for the Box class. Of course I don't expect people to check all vertex/texture coordinates...

Comment: The code I used to turn the box around is removed, it was only a line `glRotatef()` in the gameloop, to see the box at all sides. Now I only have a gameloop, that calls the box.render() every frame.

Comment: I managed in isolating the problem. When I create an indices array, and give every vertex coordinate its own unique index, and I draw the box with `glDrawElements` in stead of `glDrawArrays`, it works fine. My conclusions are: 1) The vertex coordinates *are* correct. 2) the problem is probably caused by using `glDrawArrays`. Even though it works now, it's still not okay, because the way it works correctly is very cumbersome (becaue of the unnecessary, long indices array).
I'm curious why `glDrawArrays` did so strange at some runs. While the data passed in seems right.

Answer (score 0):

Since in the pictures you show the box from different angles, my best guess would still be, there is something wrong with the vertices. So maybe you dont get different results everytime you run it, but actually only see the same result from different angles, which makes the object appear differently because of faceculling or other reasons.

Try rendering a quad (easier to determin right vertices) and see if you still get the same result.

Comment: I changed the code so it doesn't turn the box around, but still there's another result at every run. When rendering a single quad or triangle, there are no (visible) problems. If there would be something wrong with the vertices, the result would at least be the same on every run.

Comment: True. Well, in this stage i assume every object rendered on the screen is defined by vertices. So if something weird shows up, it means there are vertices out of place. Assuming you got them right when defining the quad, and also asuming you dont intentionally change them around in your shader, the only other places i can think of, where vertices are manipulated are when transforming and projecting them. So as Rappid pointed out, it would be helpfull to see your projection and also transformation code.